# Overriding OnDisappearing in custom Renderer Xamarin. Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, custom-renderer

I want to call a base.Dispose() on the OnDisappearing() from my Android project in Xamarin.Forms.

I have done something like this :-

namespace Project.Mobile.Droid

```
{
    [assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(ItemListPage), typeof(DisposeRenderer))]
    class DisposeRenderer : ViewRenderer
    {
          public DisposeRenderer() { }

    }
}
```

How can I go ahead with this?
Iam new to Xamarin.Forms, so it would be a great help if someone helps me on this.

Comment: Does it accept the ExportRenderer attribute on top of the class? I think it should on top of the namespace.

Answer (score 0):

As long as your ItemListPage implements IDisposable, you could try the following :-

```
using System;
using DisposableControlSample;
using DisposableControlSample.Droid;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(DisposablePage), typeof(DisposablePageRenderer))]
namespace DisposableControlSample.Droid
{
    public class DisposablePageRenderer : PageRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Page> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            e.NewElement.Disappearing += (sender, args) =>
            {
                var disposablePage = sender as IDisposable;

                if (disposablePage != null)
                {
                    disposablePage.Dispose();
                }
            };
        }
    }
}
```